# sliding divs with text navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

It's me again :) today am trying to develop a sliding divs with text navigation, i mean that i can edit the `nav` not only generated bullets. say that we have three `div`s containing images and text and i need to center a navigation menu of three different links.. also if you can help me in that, if the current slider is number 3 and I clicked on `nav` item number 1 I want it to jump to 1 without seeing 2 during the scrolling

here is the original code i need to learn how to develop it  http://www.alfaromeo.co.uk/models/giulietta#dynamism

links to a similar article or any help in general would be very appreciated

```css
.item--mobile .slider-item__wrap{height:300px;overflow:hidden}
.row-slide,.row-wrap{*zoom:1;clear:both;position:relative}
.row-slide:before,.row-slide:after,.row-wrap:before,.row-wrap:after{content:" ";display:table}
.row-slide:after,.row-wrap:after{clear:both}
.row-slide .content__text .animated-line,.row-wrap .content__text .animated-line{top:12px}

@media screen and (min-width:769px){.slider-menu{width:100%;font-size:0;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:42px;left:0;text-align:center;z-index:4}
.slider-menu>ul,.slider-menu>ul>li{display:inline-block}
.slider-menu>ul{padding:0;font-size:0;width:100%}
.slider-menu>ul>li{font:14px/14px "ApexNew-Medium",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#000;background-color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;border-right:1px solid #000;cursor:pointer;max-width:180px;width:100%;text-align:center}
.slider-menu>ul>li:first-child{position:relative}
.slider-menu>ul>li:first-child:before{content:"";width:90%;height:1px;position:absolute;bottom:5px;left:5%;background:#8f0c25}
.slider-menu>ul>li:last-child{border-right:0}
.slider-menu>ul>li.active{background-color:#8f0c25;color:#fff}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1366px){.slider-menu>ul>li{max-width:220px}
}
```

```html
<div class="row-slide">

<div class="slider-item-wrap">
            
    <div class="slide current">
         images and text goes here 1
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
         images and text goes here 2
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
         images and text goes here 3
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-menu">
    <ul>
    <li class="current"><a>link to slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a>link to slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a>link to slide 3</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you view the source code? You just have to copy that and the related css info. Then make a test page and change the style to your needs. view-source:http://www.alfaromeo.co.uk/models/giulietta#efficiency

Comment: mlegg, i did that but on a smaller scale and less data my main problem is the script am new into java script and very confused

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to develop a **carousel**.

There are several javascript and jQuery carousels, for example [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and 
[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

It will be much easier to use a plugin or somebody else's solution for this. Download one of the examples and follow the site's instructions for how to integrate it into your own site.

Otherwise, use your browser's Developer Tools or script debugging feature to study the script for that site you pointed to. You can also study the code of jCarousel and Slick, for example, or any library.

Here is a very simple example of a custom carousel I threw together that you can study. It uses progressive enhancement and takes advantage of scrolling so that even without javascript users still get a decent experience and can flip through content. (Though you could easily tailor it to hide the scrollbar by swapping images instead, for example).

The main parts are: 1) styling so that only one content panel shows at a time, and 2) the logic to animate the sliding of the panels when user navigates.

```js
$(".slider-menu a").on("click", function() {
  var $current = $(".slide.current");
  var $li = $(this).closest("li");
  var idx = $li.index();
  if (idx !== $current.index()) {
    $(".slider-menu li.current").removeClass("current");
    $li.addClass("current");
    var $next = $(".slide").eq(idx);
    $current.removeClass("current");
    $next.addClass("current");
    var $carousel = $(".slider-item-wrap");
    var left = $carousel[0].scrollLeft + $next.position().left;
    $carousel.animate({
      scrollLeft: left
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.row-slide,
.slider-item-wrap {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row-slide {} .slider-item-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.slider-menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.slider-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider-menu li {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
}
.slider-menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
.slider-menu li.current,
.slider-menu li.current:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-slide">
  <div class="slider-item-wrap">
    <div class="slide current red">
      images and text goes here 1
    </div>
    <div class="slide blue">
      images and text goes here 2
    </div>
    <div class="slide green">
      images and text goes here 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a>link to slide 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>link to slide 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>link to slide 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i will for sure . about this part "use your browser's Developer Tools or script debugging feature to study the script for that site you pointed to" can you make it more clear or give example for these tools please?

Comment: Put together code for a simple example. Google "developer tools" or "javascript debugging" for your browser. If you are debugging on iPad you will need to use your OSX machine to debug remotely through Safari. If debugger is not available just download the source code and study it. Make sure you understand each part before moving on to the next, etc. My code is pretty simple and should be easy to follow with a little patience.

Comment: okay its working! but sorry i've more question, when i tried to place more than one carousel something goes wrong. the navigation appears once and controls the two sliders!

Comment: you need to use unique identifiers for each carousel. You are getting into different topic area here. please accept current solution and post new question with your updated code.